# Any Python ORM make full use of NoSQL's schema-less feature?

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, nosql

I tried `Django-nonrel`(which is a NoSQL fork of Django project) with `MongoDB`. In it's ORM, class can only inherit from abstract class, so even two class are inherit from the same base class, they are saved into different collections in MongoDB.

This design added a pre-defined schema to the schema-less database, every collection has its unique schema now.

What I want is, if ClassA and ClassB are inherited from BaseClass, every instance of ClassA and ClassB should be put in the same collection ( or something similar in NoSQL other than MongoDB )

Comment: what is the point of an ORM for a document database that is not in any way relational? Why all the abstraction? If you used the db driver directly, it'd be easier I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of Django-nonrel is to maintain the same behaviors as Django's ORM has, but to allow use of non-relational storage backends. Since Django doesn't permit multiple different models to be stored in the same (relational) table, I'm not surprised to learn that Django-nonrel doesn't either.

If you want the behavior you have described, you might check out [Mongoengine](http://www.mongoengine.org/), an ODM (object-document mapper) for MongoDB, which is inspired by and has a similar feel to the Django ORM, but which allows more flexible schemas and behaviors, like the one you've described.

In particular, when using Mongoengine, you can create multiple classes whose records are stored in the same collection like:

```
class BlogPost(mongoengine.Document):
    create_date = mongoengine.DateTimeField()
    mod_date = mongoengine.DateTimeField()

    title = mongoengine.StringField()

    meta = {
        'abstract': True,
    }

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk:
            self.create_date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.mod_date = datetime.utcnow()

        super(BlogPost, self).save()

class TextBlogPost(BlogPost):
    body = mongoengine.StringField()

class ImageBlogPost(BlogPost):
    image = mongoengine.FileField()
    caption = mongoengine.StringField()
```

Since `TextBlogPost` and `ImageBlogPost` both inherit from `BlogPost`, they will both be saved in the same collection (by default, named "blog_post").